# Is a single line, line segment, or ray a valid angle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

After online research and several definitions of the term *angle* it seems they all fit a short set of restrictions for what defines an angle, "a shape formed by two rays that intersect at a point called the *vertex*."

Given this definition a ray or line segment **on its own** is not an angle because it would require at least *two* of either to form the shape. So how then is an angle of zero degrees a valid angle? Is it not the exact same as a line segment or ray?

Is an angle of zero degrees not actually an angle or is it for some reason an exception to the rule?

Comment: A 0º angle is made up of two lines, directly on top of each other. Therefore the angle, or the space between them is 0º.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero degrees actually does fall valid under that definition because any single ray or line can be drawn as two overlapping rays or lines (just copy the other one!). In that essence, the two lines have an angle of zero because there is no space between them, they are the same.

I'm not sure if you are familiar with the topic of vectors, but you can also define angles as the cosine of this formula

$$
\theta = \arccos\left(\dfrac{\vec u\cdot \vec v}{||\vec u|| *||\vec v||}\right)
$$

And if $\vec u = \vec v$ then you get

$$
\theta = \arccos \left(1\right) = 0
$$